# Model Attributes null with Thymeleaf-spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a weird error that is driving me crazy.
I have a Controller with two different Get Methods - for two different url mappings.
URL1 works perfectly fine, with URL2, I get

> [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-3] Exception processing template 
>      "questionnaireForm": Error during execution of processor 
>     'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.StandardEachAttrProcessor' 
>      (questionnaireForm:10)
>   caused by
>      java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.thymeleaf.context.WebSessionVariablesMap.hashCode(WebSessionVariablesMap.java:276) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]

After hours of checking each line, it's clear that my Controller Get Method is adding a non-null object to the Model.addAttribute before calling the view.
I've also removed all of my code from the template and just added the following to troubleshoot:

```
<tr th:each="var : ${#vars}">
<td th:text="${var.key}"></td>
<td th:text="${var.value}"></td>
```

This is returning the same null error as well!
The only thing i could find on the web was a bug with Thymeleaf 2.1.4 that was caused by not having a HttpSession Object
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/349

but then again, my URL1 works fine!
I haven't posted any code here because I'm not sure what else to post, please ask!

EDIT: Added Controller Code. `/admin/questions` is URL1 that works fine, '/admin/questionnaires' is URL2 that doesn't work.

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
private QuestionRepository questionRepository;
private EQuestionnaireRepository eQuestionnaireRepository;
private EQuestionnaire eQuestionnaire;


@Autowired
public AdminController(QuestionRepository questionRepository,
                       EQuestionnaireRepository
                       eQuestionnaireRepository){
    this.questionRepository = questionRepository;
    this.eQuestionnaireRepository = eQuestionnaireRepository;
    eQuestionnaire = eQuestionnaireRepository.findAll().get(0);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/questions", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String questionForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("question", new Question());
        return "questionForm";

}//-->This Works fine

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/questions", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveQuestion(@ModelAttribute Question newQuestion, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if( bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.println(bindingResult);
        System.out.println("BINDING RESULTS ERROR");
        return "questionForm";
    }
    questionRepository.save(newQuestion);
    return "questionForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/Questionnaires", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String QuestionnaireForm(Model model){
model.addAttribute("ListofQ",eQuestionnaire.getQuestionList());
    return "questionnaireForm";
```

UPDATE: I changed over to thymeleaf 2.1.5-SNAPSHOT, and now I'm not getting the previously mentioned error - but a different error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "ask.questionText"     
(questionnaireForm:13)
```

So now, the object reference is null in the template. It's not null when i put it into the Model (i've got System.out of the getQuestionText method inside the GET method, so thats confirmed) 
This is the simple code I'm trying in the template:

```
<table>
  <tr th:each= "ask : ${ListofQ}"></tr>
  <tr th:text= "${ask.questionText}"></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the Question Object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Questions")
public class Question {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long ID;
private int sequence;
private String questionText;
private int weightage;
private String option1 = "option1";
private String option2 = "option2";
private String option3 = "option3";

public Question() {

}
public Long getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(Long iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public int getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}
public void setSequence(int sequence) {
    if (sequence > 0) this.sequence = sequence;
}
public String getQuestionText() {
    return questionText;
}
public void setQuestionText(String questionText) {
    this.questionText = questionText;
}
public int getWeightage() {
    return weightage;
}
public void setWeightage(int weightage) {
    this.weightage = weightage;
}

public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;

}
public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;

}
public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;

}
public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}
public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}
public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}
```

Comment: For starters add the Controller and those two methods.

Comment: What is `URL2` that doesn't work?

Comment: you means you need use @property file key and value in thymeleaf html page?

Comment: URL2 is /admin/Questionnaires. I'm editing the question with updates

Comment: Can you please post the Question class code? Are you sure that Question has questionText property?

Comment: @Milan, just added the Question POJO.

Comment: Ok, next question, does questionText actually have value? Can you debug and make sure of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

output in "each" need to be in the same statement , i think this will work for you

```
<table>
  <tr th:each= "ask : ${ListofQ}" th:text= "${ask.questionText}"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the model object to the Thymeleaf.

Try something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/Questionnaires", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView QuestionnaireForm(Model model){
    return return new ModelAndView("questionnaireForm", "ListofQ",eQuestionnaire.getQuestionList());
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that Model.addAttribute works just as well? I'm using it in other code and it works....is there any particular reason to use ModelAndView in this case?

Comment: You are right. According to this http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html model.addAttribute should work.
Just for test, try the ModelAndView option, see if it works.